# CSS Selector doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, security, xss

I am developing a website which relies on user input to create scripts
As a defense in depth solution I am adding a blacklist protection to omit all links with an external source. I tried the following code snippet but it doesn't work (my browser supports it because w3schools sample works on it) :

```
    [href~=//]
    {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you'll want to use CSS for this because even though you're hiding the link from the user, it's still in the page in the DOM, which means it can still be accessed. I suggest JS to actually remove it, not just hide it.

Comment: U are right, in fact i am doing so to hide it from other victims, preventing some XSS's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a subtle different in the selectors that you are using :

- `[attribute~="value"]` - This checks for a specific word (i.e. wrapped in white-space or the exact string)
- `[attribute*="value"]` - This checks if a given set of text is contained at all.

You'll see that the second approach works, whereas the first does not.

Additionally, you'll want to ensure that you have the specific element you are targeting and that you are wrapping your value within quotes, as seen below  :

```
a[href*='//']{
        display: none;
}
```

**Example**

```css
a[href*='//'] {
  display: none;
}

/* Added to demonstrate selector differences */
a[href~='//'] {
  color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h4>[href*="value"] Examples</h4>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>Hidden</a>
<a href='stackoverflow.com'>Shown</a>
<a href='Check // this out'>Green</a>

<h4>[href~="value"] Examples</h4>
<a href='a//'>Hidden (since not whole "word")</a>
<a href='//'>Shown (as exact)</a>
<a href='//a'>Hidden (since not whole "word")</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a[href*="//"]{
  display:none;
}
```

Select all a objects whose href contains '//'

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85cb5mwz/)